# What can we say about the spectrum of the difference of positive elements?

Tags: spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra with $a,b\in\mathcal{A}_+$ such that $\|a\|<\|b\|$. Does it follow that $a-b\not\in\mathcal{A}_+$?

I can find very little about the spectrum of the sum or difference of two elements. But I believe there should at least be some useful observations to be made for positive elements. For example, I did prove the following.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra with $a\in\mathcal{A}$ and $b\in\mathcal{A}_+$ such that $\|a\|<\|b\|$. If $C^*(a,b)$ is abelian, then $a-b\not\in\mathcal{A}_+$?

*Proof:* Since $b\in\mathcal{A}_+$ we have $\|b\|=r(b)$, so we find $x\in\sigma(b)$ with $x>\|a\|$. Then there exists a homomorphism $h$ on $C^*(a,b)$ such that $h(b)=x$. We find $h(a-b)=h(a)-h(b)\leq\|a\|-h(b)<0$. Since $h(a-b)\in\sigma(a-b)$, we get $a-b\not\in\mathcal{A}_+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false, as is the proof you give for the commutative case (the fallacy lies in $\|b\|-h(a)<0$).  Consider $\mathcal A=\mathbb C$, $a=4$, and $b=7$.

**EDIT**

Note that now the claim is equivalent to "If $0\leq a\leq b$, then $\|a\|\leq\|b\|$."  This can be proven as follows:  By functional calculus, we have $b\leq\|b\|$, and thus $a\leq\|b\|$.  Applying functional calculus again gives $\|a\|\leq\|b\|$.

Comment: You are totally correct. I stupidly made a mistake in my writing, I confused $a$ and $b$, since I first used different names and then changed them :/ I fixed it now. The question should make sense now.

Comment: No problem.  I edited my response, let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: First, I think you swapped that $a$ and $b$ now. If that is the case, that is very understandable :P Second, I don't see how the statement is equivalent. Last, how does $b\leq\|a\|$ give $\|b\|\leq\|a\|$?

Comment: I may have swapped them.  I swapped them again, because this looks more natural.  The statement I have is the contrapositive to the statement you made.  The negation of the statement $a-b\notin\mathcal A_+$ is $0\leq a-b$ or $b\leq a$, and the negation of $\|a\|<\|b\|$ is $\|b\|\leq\|a\|$.   Lastly, if $\lambda$ is a positive real number, then $0\leq b\leq\lambda$ means that $\sigma(b)\subset[0,\lambda]$, and since the norm of $b$ is its spectral radius, we have $\|b\|\leq\lambda$.  Now put $\lambda=\|a\|$.

Comment: Ah of course. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!